# In excel, how do you multiply and sum alternating cells in a row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For now I am just using

`=(A1*C1)+(B1*D4)+(E1*G1)+(F1*H1)+...`

but this is a long row of cells. they just alternate and I was hoping there was a simpler way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the last cell in the range is `H1`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:F1,C1:H1,N(ISODD(EVEN(COLUMN(A1:F1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:F1))+1)/2)))`

Or, for Office 365:

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:F1,C1:H1,N(ISODD(EVEN(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A1:F1)))/2)))`

Note the deliberately offset ranges (`A1:F1` and `C1:H1`).

Comment: Thanks. worked perfectly

Comment: You're welcome!